# Setting language variant in polyglossia removes small caps from font

Tags: polyglossia, small-caps, libertinus

I've come across a strange interaction between `polyglossia` and certain fonts (I've only tested `Libertinus Serif`, though). When specifying the language variant `bokmal` for the language `norwegian`, small caps don't work in the Libertinus font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant = bokmal]{norwegian}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}
\textsc{abc}
\end{document}
```

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/LibertinusSerif(1)/m/sc` undefined
>
> (Font)              using `TU/LibertinusSerif(1)/m/n` instead on input
> line 9.

When removing the language variant or using the default font, small caps appear as usual. Although I assume this is some strange bug, I would like to know how I can work around this until it has been fixed.

Comment: well it is the font. If the language is set to norwegian it not longer offers the small caps feature.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But why would that be? If the font has small caps, it has small caps. And why only when adding `variant = bokmal`?

Comment: open type fonts can activate some features only for some languages. But I can't tell you why libertine does this. With the variant the language NOR is set (which this it fails as the font knows this tag), without it NYN is used.

Comment: There are bokmal/Norwegian small caps in font Noto Serif. (So perhaps lualatex can be used to reset the font language?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset the language for small caps:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant = bokmal]{norwegian}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[SmallCapsFont={Libertinus Serif},SmallCapsFeatures={Language=Default,Letters = SmallCaps}]

\begin{document}

\textsc{abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This only works when including `SmallCapsFont={Libertinus Serif}` and putting `Language = Default` as a feature before `Letters = SmallCaps`. I'm puzzled by both. What other small caps font would be activated other than the font that's already set as the main font?

Comment: you don't get a different font. You get the same font but with other open type features, most importantly with Language=Default instead of Language=Norwegian.

Comment: I realize that - it was more of a rhetorical question. As `SmallCapsFont` is nested within `setmainfont`, why would it have any effect to specify the small caps font as the same font as the main font? The font is Libertinus also without `SmallCapsFont`. It does have an effect, but I don't understand why.